# Shutdown command in batch behaves like sleep command, how to fix?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I created this batch file from the help of other posts on this site mixed with what beginner knowledge I have. 
It's purpose is to either shutdown, or sleep the computer after a set time so I can leave it to complete a task without running all night after it completes.

Problem is, if I run the shutdown command, it will seemingly power off but when turned on resumes any open apps and sometimes doesn't start up correctly. (Example, takes 1-2 times of powering on for it to actually power on instead of turning off moments later again.)

Running freshly installed Windows 10 home x64

Here is my complete code for the file:

```
@echo off 
color 3F
mode con: cols=52 lines=5
echo Minutes until event?
set /p min=
set /a sec="min * 60"
echo Shutdown-1 or Sleep-2
set /p eventtype=
if %eventtype%==1 goto :shutdown
if %eventtype%==2 goto :sleep
:shutdown (
cls
echo Shutdown in %min% minutes at:
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set timeHour=%%a
   set timeMinute=%%b
   set timeSeconds=%%c
)
rem Convert HH:MM to minutes + %min%
set /A newTime=timeHour*60 + timeMinute + %min%
rem Convert new time back to HH:MM
set /A timeHour=newTime/60, timeMinute=newTime%%60
rem Adjust new hour and minute
if %timeHour% gtr 23 set timeHour=0
if %timeHour% lss 10 set timeHour=0%timeHour%
if %timeMinute% lss 10 set timeMinute=0%timeMinute%
echo %timeHour%:%timeMinute%:%timeSeconds%
timeout /t %sec% /nobreak
start shutdown.exe /s /t 00
)
:sleep (
cls
echo Sleep in %min% minutes at:
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set timeHour=%%a
   set timeMinute=%%b
   set timeSeconds=%%c
)
rem Convert HH:MM to minutes + %min%
set /A newTime=timeHour*60 + timeMinute + %min%
rem Convert new time back to HH:MM
set /A timeHour=newTime/60, timeMinute=newTime%%60
rem Adjust new hour and minute
if %timeHour% gtr 23 set timeHour=0
if %timeHour% lss 10 set timeHour=0%timeHour%
if %timeMinute% lss 10 set timeMinute=0%timeMinute%
echo %timeHour%:%timeMinute%:%timeSeconds%
timeout /t %sec% /nobreak
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
)
```

Comment: TY for formatting Compo

Comment: Try just running the line  `start shutdown.exe /s /t 00` .. does it shutdown properly in that case or not?

Comment: Change line 11 to just `:shutdown`; Change line 31 to just `:sleep`; Remove all content at lines 30 & 50. Then make sure hibernation is disabled, `Powercfg -H OFF` before trying it again

Comment: @Plirkee yes it does work as intended.

Comment: @Compo changes made, confirmed hibernation turned off (Forgot to do that since reinstalling Windows thanks for reminder. Have SSD don't want hibernation going on.) Will test to see how it goes, seems when run with under 5 minutes to event works but sometimes when longer (2+ hours) I get this issue so will see what happens.

Comment: OK so there is contradiction between your 2 last answers ... how come  `/t 00` *does not* shutdown, but at the same time  `"seems when run with under 5 minutes to event *works*"`. However, based on your last answer, I think you should change your power settings so that it won't go to sleep after being idle for a period of time ... take a look [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-keeps-going-into-sleep-after-1-minute/787e8cea-32ce-4ea0-a281-13c32a75352d?auth=1)... might help.

Comment: @Plirkee "When plugged in PC goes to sleep after" set to never. It does indeed contradict, I am not sure the reason myself as I had this issue with my previous OS installation (SSD died got replacement just recently) and can confirm on the previous installation sleep was set to never. I did forget to do that this time around though, changed now and will test to see if resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now works! Thanks to @Compo and @Plirkee for their input.

Here is the edited fully functional code should anyone want to use it themselves:

```
@echo off
color 3F
mode con: cols=52 lines=5
echo Minutes until event?
set /p min=
set /a sec="min * 60"
echo Shutdown-1 or Sleep-2
set /p eventtype=
if %eventtype%==1 goto :shutdown
if %eventtype%==2 goto :sleep
:shutdown
cls
echo Shutdown in %min% minutes at:
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set timeHour=%%a
   set timeMinute=%%b
   set timeSeconds=%%c
)
rem Convert HH:MM to minutes + %min%
set /A newTime=timeHour*60 + timeMinute + %min%
rem Convert new time back to HH:MM
set /A timeHour=newTime/60, timeMinute=newTime%%60
rem Adjust new hour and minute
if %timeHour% gtr 23 set timeHour=0
if %timeHour% lss 10 set timeHour=0%timeHour%
if %timeMinute% lss 10 set timeMinute=0%timeMinute%
echo %timeHour%:%timeMinute%:%timeSeconds%
timeout /t %sec% /nobreak
shutdown /p
:sleep
cls
echo Sleep in %min% minutes at:
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set timeHour=%%a
   set timeMinute=%%b
   set timeSeconds=%%c
)
rem Convert HH:MM to minutes + %min%
set /A newTime=timeHour*60 + timeMinute + %min%
rem Convert new time back to HH:MM
set /A timeHour=newTime/60, timeMinute=newTime%%60
rem Adjust new hour and minute
if %timeHour% gtr 23 set timeHour=0
if %timeHour% lss 10 set timeHour=0%timeHour%
if %timeMinute% lss 10 set timeMinute=0%timeMinute%
echo %timeHour%:%timeMinute%:%timeSeconds%
timeout /t %sec% /nobreak
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that your way of shutting down is by using `shutdown.exe`. You could simply use the `shutdown` command. Instead of `start shutdown.exe /s /t 00` you could have `shutdown /s /t 00`.

This may or may not be the solution but is worth the try. At the least, this saves you 10 characters.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with their shutdown command although it could be reduced to `shutdown /p`

Comment: If it is not a solution then it is not an answer and should be posted as a comment.  As @Compo has said there is nothing wrong with the way they are using shutdown.